# CSS: Flexbox within Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I was playing around with the flexboxes a little and wanted to combine a column and row container. The question I have is:

Why do the row elements placed within the column not span the entire width of the flex-container?

The example code is shown here: [js-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cq0ecd5u/)

HTML:

```css
/* CSS: */

.flex-container {
  color: blue;
  background-color:yellow;
  text-decoration: bold;
  text-size: 1em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
}
.horizontal {
  flex-direction:row;
  background-color: red;
}

.vertical {
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex-container vertical">
  <div class=flex-item>1 </div>
  <div class=flex-item>2 </div>
  <div class="flex-container horizontal" >
    <div class=flex-item>3a </div>
    <div class=flex-item>3b </div>
    <div class=flex-item>3c </div>
  </div>
  <div class=flex-item>4 </div>
  <div class=flex-item>5 </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Because your `.horizontal` container isn't wide enough. Add `width: 100%;` to it.

Comment: Well that was rather straightforward ;) I thought I had tried that..

Comment: Hehe, i'm sorry. Coffee hasn't kicked in yet. I also don't really know why the width isn't automatically restricted, therefore posting this as a comment until I found the solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because of the way Flexbox works.

Since the `.horizontal` container is a flex child itself, it automatically adjusts to the size of the other children. Only allowing space for the overflowing content, which are the children of the `.horizontal` itself.

Manually applying the width will result in the space being created for the items, and the `justify-content: space-between` will kick in.

Solution, change the following rule:

```
.horizontal {
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this produces the desired result. The solution from Danield also produces a wide row, but the elements are not center-aligned any more

Answer (score 3):

Since you have set `align-items:center;` on the flex container, in addition to being centered - the items also only take up the minimum amount of space that they need.

If you hadn't set this property - then the default value of `stretch` would have kicked in and the items would take up the full width.

Then, like @Michael_B pointed out you could apply `align-self:center` on the flex items to center the items on the cross axis.

```css
.flex-container {
  color: blue;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-decoration: bold;
  text-size: 1em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.horizontal {
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: red;
}

.vertical {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-item {
  align-self: center;
  /* center each flex item along the cross axis */
  text-align: center;
  /* horizontally center content within flex item */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex-container vertical">
    <div class=flex-item>1 </div>
    <div class=flex-item>2 </div>
    <div class="flex-container horizontal">
      <div class=flex-item>3a </div>
      <div class=flex-item>3b </div>
      <div class=flex-item>3c </div>
    </div>
    <div class=flex-item>4 </div>
    <div class=flex-item>5 </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate why applying `align-items: stretch` on `.horizontal` doesn't work?

Comment: @Roberrrt It does 'work' except that you need to note that the stretching that occurs is on the **cross axis**, so when the flex direction is column - stretching occurs horizontally, and when the flex direction is row - the stretching occurs vertically

Comment: This answer nails the reasoning. For a pure flex solution, remove `align-items: center` from the container. Add `align-self: center` to the flex items you want centered. The middle item (3a/b/c) will stretch by default: https://jsfiddle.net/cq0ecd5u/2/

Comment: @Michael_B, thanks much appreciated, I added that into the post.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `width: 100%` to your horizontal flexbox and `flex: 1` to the items within it I got this:

```css
   body {
     background-color: black
   }

   .flex-container {
     color: blue;
     background-color: yellow;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     align-items: center;
   }

   .horizontal {
     flex-direction: row;
     background-color: red;
     width: 100%; /*this line was added*/
   }
   
   /*these lines*/
   .horizontal .flex-item {
     flex: 1;
   }
   /*ware added*/

   .vertical {
     flex-direction: column;
   }

   .flex-item {
     background: tomato;
     padding: 5px;
     width: 100px;
     height: 75px;
     margin: 5px;
     line-height: 75px;
     color: white;
     font-size: 3em;
     text-align: center;
   }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex-container vertical">
    <div class="flex-item">1 </div>
    <div class="flex-item">2 </div>
    <div class="flex-container horizontal">
      <div class="flex-item">3a</div>
      <div class="flex-item">3b</div>
      <div class="flex-item">3c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">4</div>
    <div class="flex-item">5</div>
  </div>
</body>
```