# How to set div height 100% to its container with flex and keep centering in vertical alignment?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I tried to centering text and button using flexbox, and keep the column equally. But I have difficulties how to set column height as 100% to its container. When I set height to 100%, its vertical alignment not in middle anymore. I don't want achieving the result using table or javascript.

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  border-top: solid 1px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
  align-items: center;
  height:48px;
}
.column {
  flex-basis:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
.mid-col {
  border-left:solid 1px;
  border-right:solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div>50</div>
    <div>Following</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column mid-col">
    <div>50</div>
    <div>Followers</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <button>Follow</button>
  </div>  
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stomata/a0d9Lyov/)

Comment: I want achieve as the border in middle to have maximum height. When I set .column {height: 100%} the align-items is not centering anymore. It move to top.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40864770/703717 - that's probably the issue if I understand you correctly..... so you should do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/danield770/jjwzymgw/

Comment: Yes Danield! This is what I'm looking for. I tried before with align-self but not working, until I saw your code with "flex-direction" Thank your very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use nested flexbox if you want the `column`s to get 100% height of `container` - add this:

```
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
```

to `column` and remove `align-items: center` from `container` (so that the default `align-items: stretch` may take effect).

(You are not able to set 100% height for `column` now as you have `align-items: center` applied to your `container`)

See demo below:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border-top: solid 1px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
  height: 48px;
}
.column {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.mid-col {
  border-left: solid 1px;
  border-right: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div>50</div>
    <div>Following</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column mid-col">
    <div>50</div>
    <div>Followers</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <button>Follow</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Kukuz, thanks for your explanation! I accept your answer as a final answer for me, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without using table just by using `display: table` for parent and `display: table-cell; vertical align: middle;` to child. If you want that using flex itself, I have implemented that in below example.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            border-top: solid 1px;
            border-bottom: solid 1px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 300px;
        }
        
        .column {
            text-align: center;
            width: 33%;
        }
        
        .column--top {
            align-self: flex-start;
        }
        
        .column--bottom {
            align-self: flex-end;
        }
        
        .mid-col {
            border-left: solid 1px;
            border-right: solid 1px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="column">
            <div>50</div>
            <div>Following</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column mid-col">
            <div>50</div>
            <div>Followers</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <button>Follow</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi thank you Nitheesh, thanks for your working code. But I want to dig more by using flex. I heard that flex is good for its performance.

Comment: I have updated the code. Please check whether it fits your requirement.

Comment: Hi Nitheesh, personally I like your first code (before edited) where the equally divide is using flex not using 33%, thanks again